# Memory: how does the compiler choose where to store variables?

Tags: c++, c, memory, compiler-construction, runtime

Given two functions, func1 and f2, with the following signatures:

```
void func1(){
    int baba = 12345;
    // printf the value of baba here
}

void f2(){
    int loo;
    //printf the value of loo here
}
```

...if I run my int main, which only has func1 then f2:

```
int main(){
      func1();
      f2();
}
```

...then the printed value of both baba and loo will be 12345.  So my question is as follows:

1. Is this defined behaviour, or just something erroneous that my machine does?
2. If this isn't some erroneous thing my computer did, can you explain why the compiler chooses to store `loo` in the same address as `baba?`

**EDIT:**  I guess I should ask, if I have these EXACT two functions, will     baba and loo have the same value on ANY machine?

I understand loo's value is the result of baba's leftover  bits, and I understand that (on my machine, at least) the stacks of both are being laid out such that loo overlaps onto baba's old territory.  *Is it true* that every machine would lay these two function stacks out in such a manner that baba and loo overlap?  Using these two functions exactly as written, that is...

Comment: Think about how temporary local variables can be allocated on the stack and then it should be obvious.

Comment: 1. Its UB. 2. Its an erroneous thing in the code, not the compiler. `loo` is indeterminate. Evaluating it invokes UB. Why the same address choice was used is implementation-dependent.

Comment: If an interrupt happens between calling `func1()` and `f2()` the previous `12345` on the (below stack pointer) stack would not survive.

Comment: I think that this is undefined behaviour. The way that it works is that when you call func1 the stack is pushed and the value 12345 is put assigned to an address in the new stack frame. When you leave func1 the stack is popped back to the calling stack frame. When you call f2 the stack is again pushed and as you have the same number of parameters in both calls (none) the location in memory of loo is now where baba was, this bit of memory has not been wiped and contains the same data.

Comment: @PaulR can you explain?  I don't know much assembly so maybe I'm missing something.I know that during the creation/destruction of func1(), the space assigned to baba gets the int literal "12345" written into it.  When loo is created, it's taking that same address space.  I understand that's why the value is there, but I was wondering if it's merely coincidence that loo has the same address space.  I guess a better question would be, is loo guaranteed to always occupy that space (in THESE given functions, on every platform)

Comment: Thank you all very much for the insight!!!

Comment: I am puzzled why this question is marked as answered and linked to a different question. If it has been answered, it should be to a similar question.

Comment: @user3344003   Yeah, I was wondering the same. These are two very different questions, as mines about assembly and portability, whereas the linked one is about stacks and scope

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `f2()`, `lolo` is uninitialized.  It's content is hence **undefined**.

Most often however, the content appears to be the data that was on the stack.  By coincidence, you've first called `func1()`, which has exactly the same memory/stack layout than `f2()`. So by chance the variable contains the data that was previously stored at the same place.

This behavior is not guaranteed at all.  It only appears to work in this specific context because no other local variables were created between the two calls, and no other function call overwrites the data with other content (and the two functions have exactly the same memory layout).

Here a small picture to explain the situation in this specific case: 
[image]

Comment: I use "undefined" as in "Undefined Behaviour" i.e. the c++ standard does not define a behaviour.  But undefined/indeterminate does not mean that it's random.  So I dare to maintain:  *"It works only in this specific case on this compiler with the same compiling switches with this operating system"*